# ¿Porqué estoy recibiendo este hash vacío?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Estoy usando Devise, al enviar los datos desde el formulario (registro de usuario), inspecciono los parámetros en el controlador con

```
 render plain: params.inspect
```

y obtengo lo siguiente como resultado:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"H2rNXQCfedwIKrKNtaNQlTGU+EyENNKvR57qYz5qzpggiu4xd3TE4QCdEsPYcq97mEe0FLcBHwhNQQvT15hlzw==", "user"=>{"nombre"=>"test5", "apellido"=>"", "cargo"=>"", "telefono"=>"", "email"=>"test5@mail.com", "direccion"=>"", "contrato"=>"123", "compania"=>"", "password"=>"123123", "password_confirmation"=>"123123", "user_type"=>"Cliente"}, "commit"=>"Guardar", "controller"=>"registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

ahora si quiero acceder a contrato, haciendo lo siguiente

```
 render plain: params[:contrato].inspect
```

obtengo un hermoso:

```
nil
```

alguien sabe que rayos pasa aquí?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la información de tus parámetros:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>
  "H2rNXQCfedwIKrKNtaNQlTGU+EyENNKvR57qYz5qzpggiu4xd3TE4QCdEsPYcq97mEe0FLcBHwhNQQvT15hlzw==",
 "user"=>
  {"nombre"=>"test5",
   "apellido"=>"",
   "cargo"=>"",
   "telefono"=>"",
   "email"=>"test5@mail.com",
   "direccion"=>"",
   "contrato"=>"123",
   "compania"=>"",
   "password"=>"123123",
   "password_confirmation"=>"123123",
   "user_type"=>"Cliente"},
 "commit"=>"Guardar",
 "controller"=>"registrations",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

`contrato` está anidado dentro de `user`, por lo tanto, la manera correcta de acceder sería con `params[:user][:contrato]`.